# program ending after while and ignoring what comes after

Tags: c++

Hi I was wondering if someone could help with this, the problem is what comes after the while isn't working/being ran in the program. Is there something wrong in my code or something I have to do? Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    
    int priceArticle;
    int taxPercent;
    int total = 0;
    int totalAfterTax;
    int valueFinish = -1;
    bool isTrue = true;
    bool isTaxesTrue = true;

    while (isTrue = true) {
        cout << "How much money was the cost of your item? " << endl;
        cin >> priceArticle;
        
        if (priceArticle != valueFinish) {
            total += priceArticle;
            cout << total << endl;
        }
        if (priceArticle == valueFinish) {
            cout <<  "Your total before taxes is " << total << endl;
            isTrue = false;
            return isTrue;
        }
    }       

   
    cout << "What's the percent of taxes you must pay?" << endl;
    cin >> taxPercent;
    
    

    

}
```

Comment: You exit the function using `return`... Maybe you confused it with `break`?

Comment: shouldn't it be `while (isTrue == true) `? also as CherryDT suggested you need `break` instead of `return`

Comment: Also there is no point of returning `return isTrue` from main

Answer (score 1):

There are few bugs in your code and in the logic:

1. First of all, your condition inside the while loop is not written as condition. You wrote *while(isTrue **=** true)* 
   instead of using the condition operator ==.
   This may cause the problem you described, which the code is stuck on the while loop.
2. The second if statement condition can not be met (logically) because you set  *valueFinish = -1* .
3. You used  *return isTrue*  when not needed, you are not inside a function that has to return a value.
    *isTrue = false;*  is all you needed.
4. I'm not sure what was you task but it seems like there is a logical mistake in the conditions. You compare *priceArticle*  to *valueFinish* instead of the accumulative variable  *total* and you basically don't use it at all.
   I suppose you wanted to break out of the while once the total value crosses some condition.

Here is a code that implement all the points I mentioned above:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    
    int priceArticle;
    int taxPercent;
    int total = 0;
    int totalAfterTax;
    int valueFinish = 200;
    bool isTrue = true;
    bool isTaxesTrue = true;

    while (isTrue == true) {
        cout << "How much money was the cost of your item? " << endl;
        cin >> priceArticle;
        
        if (total+priceArticle < valueFinish) {
            total += priceArticle;
            cout << total << endl;
        }
        else {
            total += priceArticle;
            cout <<  "Your total before taxes is " << total << endl;
            isTrue = false;
            // return isTrue;
        }
    }       

   
    cout << "What's the percent of taxes you must pay?" << endl;
    cin >> taxPercent;
}
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (isTrue = true)
```

Mean to run until `isTrue` variable is changed to false and every time the while loop run to the end it change `isTrue` to true (because is one `=` and not two `==`)

```
if (priceArticle == valueFinish) {
            cout <<  "Your total before taxes is " << total << endl;
            isTrue = false;
            return isTrue;
        }
```

This is the only place when `isTrue` is changed. After it is changed, its return `isTrue`. After you return the function is return the value and stop. You should remove the return for making the code down run and not return and stop the function.

I would do something like that:

```
    int priceArticle = 0;
    int taxPercent;
    int total = 0;
    int totalAfterTax;
    int valueFinish = -1;
    bool isTaxesTrue = true;

    while (priceArticle != valueFinish) {
        cout << "How much money was the cost of your item? " << endl;
        cin >> priceArticle;
        
        if (priceArticle != valueFinish) {
            total += priceArticle;
            cout << total << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout <<  "Your total before taxes is " << total << endl;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

there are two problems

1. `=` is assignment while `==` is comparison operator in c++. Therefore your `while` condition should be `isTrue == true`
2. You are using `return` statement which means that your function `main()` will return right from that point without executing anything after it. If you want to execute lines after that, you should remove the return statement.

Note: Replacing it with `break` might help when you develop your code further, but is currently unnecessary

Answer (score 0):

There are other issues in your code, but this line is producing the problem you asked about:

```
return isTrue;
```

This returns from your `int main()`, ending its execution.